# Get counters as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I have many records of products that have status.

I wanted to count the records by status and place these results as columns. I tried with case, but I have duplicated rows that differ on the status.

```
            Received   StandBy    Stocked    Pending
Product-1          2      NULL       NULL       NULL
Product-2          NULL     25       NULL       NULL
Product-1          NULL      5       NULL       NULL
```

I would like something like this

```
            Received   StandBy    Stocked    Pending
Product-1          2         5       NULL       NULL
Product-2          NULL     25       NULL       NULL
```

This is the query that I try to do without success:

```
    SELECT  
        --COALESCE(StatusID, 0) AS StatusID,  --=1,2
        ProductID,
        ProductNumber,
        DATEPART(hour,p.ArrivalDate) as ArrivalHour,
        DATEPART(minute,p.ArrivalDate) as ArrivalMinute,
        ProductWarehouseID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Received,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 2 THEN 1 END) AS StandBy,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Stocked,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID = NULL THEN 1 END) AS Pending
    FROM Product AS p
    GROUP BY 
        ProductID,
        ProductNumber,
        DATEPART(hour, p.ArrivalDate),
        DATEPART(minute, p.ArrivalDate),
        ProductWarehouseID
```

Comment: the query you posted can't give you your current result set, please post either the real query or the real result

Comment: Within cte you can use  SUM(CASE WHEN StatusID IS NULL.... Instead of = use is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have given partial query output to simply your solution.  If my understanding is correct, you may need to use an aggregate operator over your result.  An outline is here:

```
;WITH Temp AS
(   
    --Keep your current query here
)
SELECT ProductID, MAX(Received), MAX(StandBy), MAX(Stocked), MAX(Pending) 
FROM Temp 
GROUP BY ProductID --and any other grouping columns
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your key stumbling point is null + 1 = null when concat null is at its default settings in MsSql servers after Sql 2000.  You may be able to solve your issue by changing the settings of the null concat settings.  Or include the "else 0" syntax that others have posted before this post.